# did a git commit, git pull and pushed my changes to the repo. How can i send a Pull request for the one that i committed

Tags: git, github

I was searching for this across web, but couldn't find a solution.
Here is my scenario,

1) I did my local changes. Did a git commit. This will get a commit id say ABC

2) Now I did a git pull from my upstream. This had a merge conflict and after resolving it created a commit for the same.

3) Now i push these to my origin. From the origin i have to send a Pull request to my upstream.

4) While trying to send a Pull request, I see both these commits.

How can i now send only the commit that i did, that is the commit ABC (from step# 1)

Answer (score 0):

Pull requests are made between *branches* - you ask the target repo's owner to pull one of your branches to one of his.

If you want to make a pull request consisting in just a single commit, then you have to get a branch that only differs in that commit with the target one.

The best thing you can do now, I think, is `git fetch` your upstream remote, and then create a branch starting from one of it's branches. You'd normally branch off `upstream/master` (but it could be a different branch if you are not targeting `master` in your pull request). The command `git checkout -b my-feature upstream/master` would do the trick - provided those names match the ones you have.

If that worked, you're now on a brand new branch called `my-branch`, that points to the very same commit your `upstream`'s `master` branch points to. At this moment, you can `git cherry-pick` that single commit you wanted to appear in the PR (or you could manually edit the files and `git commit` again, as you'd prefer - the key is you get your commit done over there). And now, as you have this new commit in the feature branch, `git push` your branch to your own repo (say, `git push origin my-feature`). That would create (if it didn't exist, which would be the best) the `my-feature` branch in your `origin` repository, and now you can go create the pull request from `my-feature` to the `master` branch in `upstream`.

---

From what you tell, the problem seems to be that you `git pull`ed your branch - creating that merge commit - instead of using `git rebase`. That way, git would automatically tried to `cherry-pick` your commit on top of the target branch (say, `upstream/master`), and there wouldn't have appeared any merge commit.

Anyway, never forget that **git rebase is dangerous**, and you *shouldn't use it if you don't fully understand it*. You'd better [learn](http://pcottle.github.io/learnGitBranching/?NODEMO&command=level%20move2) [more](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Branching-Rebasing) [about](https://help.github.com/articles/about-git-rebase) [it](https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorial/rewriting-git-history#!rebase) [first](http://goodcode.io/blog/git-merge-rebase/), and then start guessing when and how it would be nice to use it.

If it has to be just one thing, don't ever forget the rule of thumb: never rebase public commits.